# Openssl 3.0.8 OSSL_PARAM_BLD structure

Tags: openssl

I was trying to upgrade from openssl 1.1 to Openssl 3.0.8.  I would like to access OSSL_PARAM_BLD structure for the implementation of dh(Diffie Hellman). Could you please let me know what header files am I am supposed to include for this? I have already included openssl/dh.h file. I see OSSL_PARAM_BLD is present in types.h file and the typedef ossl_param_bld_st is present in crypto/param_build.c file.

Also, please do let me know if there is any sample program available to use dh struct (DH* dh = DH_new();)  as this struct is not available in 3.0 version.

Thanks!!

I tried compiling the code by including  openssl/dh.h. I expected a successful compile but looks like the struct OSSL_PARAM_BLD is not found.